# Cannot include freetype headers on Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, include, freetype, linux-mint

```
#include <ft2build.h>
#include FT_FREETYPE_H
int main() {
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the compiler output:

```
In file included from fonttest.cpp:1:
/usr/include/ft2build.h:56:10: fatal error: 'freetype/config/ftheader.h' file not found
#include <freetype/config/ftheader.h>
     ^
1 error generated.
```

I follow [the official tutorial](http://www.freetype.org/freetype2/docs/tutorial/step1.html).

I have the packages installed:

```
i   libfreetype6        - FreeType 2 font engine, shared library files                  
i A libfreetype6:i386   - FreeType 2 font engine, shared library files                  
i   libfreetype6-dev    - FreeType 2 font engine, development files
```

File `/usr/include/freetype2/freetype/config/ftheader.h` is there.

Comment: What is the exactly command you use to compile this source file? Try to add `-I/usr/include/freetype2` to it and try again.

Comment: yes adding -I <path to freetype dir> helps, but I was wondering why installer did not add the path to a global include path lookup.

Comment: Have you tried `$ sudo apt-get install libfreetype6-dev:i386`?

Answer (score 1):

If someone out there is struggling, you can try

> sudo apt-get install libfreetype6-dev

Answer (score 0):

I think it's better to install `pkg-config`.
`pkg-config` will help the configure to find the `freetype2`.